# Multiline String in EditTextView Android

Tags: java, android, textview

i have created my EditTextView with this code:

```
    mEditTxtZusatzInfo = new EditTextBackEvent(this);
        mEditTxtZusatzInfo.setGravity(Gravity.START);
        mEditTxtZusatzInfo.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);
        mEditTxtZusatzInfo.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        mEditTxtZusatzInfo.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.edittextbackground);
```

Later i try to set the text of the EditTextView to:

```
    test sdgdf
gdf
ghu
fjh#
sfk

dfopgjpdfjgpodfjgpodfjgdfg
dfgdfg42534
```

But the Text only appears in one single line.

I looked at my text detail:

in HEX linebreaks are saved as: "0A"

Notepad++ displays the String correct!

How can i make my EditTextView to display the mulitple lines?

Thank you for your help and sorry for my bad english.

Best regards
Schwandi

EDIT:

EditText is a custom class which extends EditText.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the single line property as false using this setSingleLine();

```
mEditTxtZusatzInfo.setSingleLine(false);
```

and also you must set the height as wrap_content otherwise it will not increase its height of view

Comment: Thank you! Works perfect :). My EditView has a fixed height allready.

Answer (score 0):

use Multiline text instead of EditText in your xml file